# Egit - exclamation point on folder

Tags: git, egit

I can't seem to figure out what is meant by this symbol...
[image]

I checked here: [Egit User Guide "Icon Decorations"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Icon_Decorations), and I don't see it.

When I do a status on my branch it says my working folder is clean.
I am using 0.9.3 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely not related to EGit, and more in line with some other module behavior.
(like build path issues, as illustrated by [bug "Mark projects that have build path problems"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=215980))

[image]